# Что в этой функции еще написать что бы она работала так как надо?

Tags: javascript

Дали задачу написать функцию, которая сравнивает 2 числовых массива (А,В), и результатом выполнения функции должно быть:

- `true` в случае, если массивы одинаковы по длине, и элементы массива A равны элементам массива B;
- объект вида 
  `{result:false, bigger:[1,5,18...]}`
  где `bigger` - отсортированный по возрастанию массив, сумма элементов которого больше. Если сумма элементов одинакова - `bigger` = пустой массив.

Как пример, результат функции вот такой:

- `compare([7,2], [7,2])` →  `true`
- `compare([3,1,4], [8])` →  `{result:false, bigger:[]}`
- `compare([3,1,4], [8,2])` →  `{result:false, bigger:[2,8]}`

Длину массивов удалось сравнить, осталось сравнить содержимое массивов, как я понимаю. И как-то это отобразить. Подскажите.

Вот что я пытался сделать:

```
compare = function (a, b) {
    return a.length == b.length && a.every(function(v,i) { return v === b[i]})
};

// test
var a, b, compResult;

a = [1,2,3];
b = [1,2,3];

compResult = compare(a, b);
alert(compResult);
```

Comment: Важен ли порядок элементов? То есть, `compare([7,2], [2,7])` возвращает `true` или `false`?

Comment: нет порядок не важен

Comment: martynuk, что вы сами сделали для решения задачи? И что конкретно вам непонятно? Сейчас ваш вопрос выглядит как "напишите код за меня", такие вопросы здесь не приветствуются и закрываются.

Comment: я не знаю с чего начать, и поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: Над Вами издеваются. Функция не должна возвращать разные типы объектов, если конечно это не undefined, null или NaN. Не может она в одном случаи true, а в другом {} вернуть, это более чем не правильно.

Comment: не совсем понял, в одном случае когда массивы одинаковы это true, когда разные это false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала сравни длины, если совпадают, ставь флаг совпадающей длины. Если нет, result будет сразу false. Потом считаешь суммы, если они равны, в bigger пишешь пустоту, при этом если длины равны, а суммы в какой-то момент не равны, пишешь result=false. А если суммы разошлись, копируешь массив, сумма которого больше, и сортируешь, и выдаешь как bigger. А вот закодировать это изволь сам.